# How to parse a double quoted csv files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im trying to parse a csv that is quoted with `"'`. 
So basicaly the file looks like this:

```
"'test1'","'test2'","'test3'","'test4'"
"'value1'","'value2'",,"'value4'"
```

My attempt to parse it is the following:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

inputCsv = "test.csv"

with open(inputCsv, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, doublequote=True)
    for line in dictReader:
        pprint(line)
        # print(line["'test1'"]) # works, but only with "'test1'", not "test1" or 'test1'; also result is 'value1' not value1
```

I wanted the key to be `test1` - so i can access it with `line["test1"]` (instead of `line["'test1'"]`) and the value to be `value1`, without the additional quotes.

Is this possible without going over the whole dict and removing the quotes for each element after parsing?

Online Example:
https://repl.it/repls/WoefulDeafeningMacroinstruction

Comment: If you pass quatechar=' " ' ' " ' ?

Comment: quotechar only takes 1 char unfortunately. Tried that

Comment: What about pre-processing the file replacing `"'` and `'"` with `"`?

Comment: Is it possible to fix the problem at CSV source? Better fix where broken, and where this is broken is in the code of whoever generated this file in the first place.

Comment: I cant change the csv format that I am getting, as it is from an API I have no control over. I could however replace all the "' and '" in an extra step before parsing like GPhilo suggested. It just seemed like this was a valid csv syntax, that might be possible to parse and I just could'nt figure out how.

Comment: Have you considered reading the csv line by line and using something like match_object = re.match(this_key, ^'(?P<key_value>.*)'$. You can then use match_object.group('key_value') and build the dictionary yourself. Probably faster for larger files than parsing twice.

Comment: @Tiger_Mike: It depends on how it's encoded - especially with respect to any escapes that may be in the string. In particular, your pattern would fail if any strings happen to contain an apostrophe.

Comment: @Amadan It should still capture any apostrophes between the two enclosing ones, but you are right that will depend on encoding, but you can probably adjust the pattern to account for that if needed

Comment: @Tiger_Mike: We don't have any more realistic examples in OP's post that would show the details of encoding; but I'm always wary about throwing regexp on CSV (and this is even trickier). CSV libraries exist for a reason: it's super-easy to get caught on a corner case when home-brewing it, despite how deceptively easy CSV format looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own reader to fix the issue *during* iteration (warning: untested code, but it should at least get you started):

```
class MyReader(csv.reader):
    def __next__(self):
        row = super().__next__()
        return [value.strip("'") for value in row]

class MyDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None,
                 dialect="excel", *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(f, fieldnames, restkey, restval, dialect, *args, *kwds)
        self.reader = MyReader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit roundabout, but if we read the file *twice* as CSV, we get what we want:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from io import StringIO

inputCsv = "test.csv"

with open(inputCsv, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
    dequotedStringIO = StringIO()
    csvWriter = csv.writer(dequotedStringIO, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    csvWriter.writerows(csvReader)
    dequotedLines = dequotedStringIO.getvalue().splitlines()
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(dequotedLines, quotechar="'")
    for line in dictReader:
        print(line['test1'])
```

So first we have a straight `csv.reader` that will parse outer quotes; then we send all data back to a straight `csv.writer` and tell it to never quote anything. In effect this strips the outer double quotes in a way that respects CSV semantics, and you're left with a compliant CSV file that only has single quotes, which you can pass into `csv.DictReader` for the desired end result.